# Scala List, Parallelizable and calling from Java

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have a `scala.collection.immutable.List[WeatherData]`

In Scala, I can turn it into a parallel collection and call the reduce method:

```
val sum = myList.par.reduce(_+_)
```

I want to do the same in Java, but I can't.  First off, Eclipse tells me that the signature of #par() returns a ParSeq[WeatherData], but if I ask Eclipse to assign the result to a local variable, it gives me a `scala.collection.parallel.ParIterable<WeatherData>`.

Either way, neither of those interfaces have methods like `#reduce(...)`, so they don't help.

What do I have to do, so that I can call `#reduce(...)` from Java?

Cheers,
John

PS using Scala 2.10 M5

Comment: As is so often the case, calling Java from Scala is much easier than the reverse...

Comment: According to the Scala API docs, both [`ParIterable`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/parallel/immutable/ParIterable.html) and [`ParSeq`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/parallel/immutable/ParSeq.html) have `reduce()` methods?  Are you expecting a `reduce()` method with a different signature?

Comment: The problem seems to be calling `par` on a Scala `List` in Java. `Object res = list.par();` compiles but gives a `NoSuchMethodError` at runtime. I don't know why but my advice would be not to do this, since creating a function is going to be a nightmare as well. Just write the method in Scala and call that method from Java if need be.

Comment: @LuigiPlinge: This may be due to a bug in `scalac`.  I ran into a similar issue when calling Scala code from Java, where my code compiled but caused NoSuchMethodErrors at runtime.  I filed my example as the issue [SI-6050](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6050), which was closed as a duplicate of [SI-3452](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-3452).

Comment: does that mean the scala compiler is performing a bit of magic which we cannot do in java?

Comment: This is turning into a nice puzzle...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote some Scala:

```
val data = List(1,2,3)
val par = data.par
val result = par.reduce(_+_)
println(result)
```

Using the Java Decompiler, it is apparently this:

```
List localList = List..MODULE$.apply(Predef..MODULE$.wrapIntArray(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }));
ParSeq localParSeq = (ParSeq)localList.par();
```

Correcting it slightly, I tried this Java:

```
List localList = List$.MODULE$.apply(Predef$.MODULE$.wrapRefArray(new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3 }));
ParSeq localParSeq = (ParSeq)localList.par();
```

And like Luigi wrote, that leads to a strange `NoSuchMethodException`.

I went to the next level, and used `javap -verbose`, which gave this:

```
29: invokeinterface #40,  1; //InterfaceMethod scala/collection/Parallelizable.par:()Lscala/collection/Parallel;
```

That made me wonder what would happen if I cast to a `Parallelizable` before calling `par` in Java:

```
List localList = List$.MODULE$.apply(Predef$.MODULE$.wrapRefArray(new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3 }));
Parallelizable p = (Parallelizable)localList;       
Parallel p2 = p.par();
Integer result = (Integer) ((ParSeq)p2).reduce(adder);
System.out.println(result);
```

That prints `6`, which is right :-)

But I have to admit, I have no idea whatsoever, why I have to cast.  This has made me realise I still have a lot to learn about Java and Scala.

*Does anyone know why the cast makes a difference?*